# MongoDB unwind multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents:

```
{
  "dates": [
    1399518702000,
    1399126333000,
    1399209192000,
    1399027545000
  ],
  "dress_number": "4",
  "name": "J. Evans",
  "numbers": [
    "5982",
    "5983",
    "5984",
    "5985"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible unwind data from multiple arrays and get only paired elements from arrays:

```
{
    "dates": "1399518702000",
    "numbers": "5982"
},
{
    "dates": "1399126333000",
    "numbers": "5983"
},
{
    "dates": "1399209192000",
    "numbers": "5984"
},
{
    "dates": "1399027545000",
    "numbers": "5985"
}
```

Comment: what happen if `dates` array length and `numbers` array length not same?

Comment: They always have the same length.

Comment: The `dates` array element is a string `"[1399518702000, 1399126333000, 1399209192000, 1399027545000]"`, not an array.

Comment: @chirdam, that was mistake, thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From version 3.2 you can do it with `$unwind` on both of the arrays, `$cmp` the indexes, and `$match` only the equal indexes.

This solution will populate what you wrote in case you have only the example document. If you have more documents I don't know what you expect to get in the output, but it's solvable by grouping by _id of the document.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$dates',
            includeArrayIndex: 'dates_index',
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$numbers',
            includeArrayIndex: 'numbers_index',
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            dates: 1,
            numbers: 1,
            compare: {
                $cmp: ['$dates_index', '$numbers_index']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            compare: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            dates: 1,
            numbers: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: If I understood well, it's possible to unwind a maximum of two arrays?

Comment: @corry how did you understand that? you can unwind as many as you want. The problem is that each element will become an document, so for many unwinds, the result will be enormous db. it will be very hard to handle and they question is what you want to do with them.

Comment: I think it couldn't be possible to unwind as many as I want because of $cmp operator. I put a new question regarding this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426022/mongodb-show-children-items-in-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 4):

Starting in `Mongo 3.4`, you can use [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) to pair your array elements:

```
// { values: [23, 2, 14], items: ["aa", "bb", "cc"] }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $project: { x: { $zip: { inputs: ["$values", "$items"] } } } },
  // { x: [[23, "aa"], [2, "bb"], [14, "cc"]] }

  { $unwind: "$x" },
  // { x: [23, "aa"] }
  // { x: [2,  "bb"] }
  // { x: [14, "cc"] }

  { $project: { value: { $first: "$x" }, item: { $last: "$x" } } }
])
// { value: 23, item: "aa" }
// { value: 2,  item: "bb" }
// { value: 14, item: "cc" }
```

Once your arrays have been `$zip`ped, it's just a matter of `$unwind`ing them before creating documents out of arrays (`{ value: { $first: "$x" }, item: { $last: "$x" } }`).