# MongoDB - Convert One record with an array to multiple records in a new collection

Tags: python, mongodb

**[MongoDB shell or pyMongo]** I would like to know how to efficiently convert one record in a collection with an array in one field, to multiple records in say anew collection. So far, the only solution, I've been able to achieve is iterating the records one by one and then iterating the array in the field I want and do individual inserts. I'm hoping there's a more efficient way to do this.

*Example:*

I want to take a collection in MongoDB with structure similar to :

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "points": ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "points": ["d"]
}]
```

and convert it to something like this:

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "points": "a"
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "points": "b"
}, {
    "_id": 3,
    "points": "c"
}, {
    "_id": 4,
    "points": "d"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another version which can be expected to perform worse than @JohnnyHK's solution because of a second `$unwind` and a potentially massive `$group` but it generates integer IDs based on some order that you can specify in the `$sort` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    // flatten the "points" array to get individual documents
    $unwind: { "path": "$points" },
}, {
    // sort by some criterion
    $sort: { "points": 1 }
}, {
    // throw all sorted "points" in the very same massive array
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        "points": { $push: "$points" },
    }
}, {
    // flatten the massive array making each document's position index its `_id` field
    $unwind: {
        "path": "$points",
        includeArrayIndex: "_id"
    }
} , {
    // write results to new "result" collection
    $out: "result"
}], {
    // make sure we do not run into memory issues
    allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful. In this specific case, I don't need sorting but I'll keep this in mind when I do need it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ok with auto-generated `_id` values in the new collection, you can do this with an aggregation pipeline that uses `$unwind` to unwind the `points` array and `$out` to output the results to a new collection:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate each doc, one per points array element
    {$unwind: '$points'},

    // Remove the _id field to prompt regeneration as there are now duplicates
    {$project: {_id: 0}},

    // Output the resulting docs to a new collection, named 'newtest'
    {$out: 'newtest'}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for. An additional question, if I may - can I use unwind on two or more fields, given that the two fields always have the same number of elements in their arrays for any given record ? example: '[{
    "points": ["a", "b", "c"],
 "scores": [1,2,3]
}, {
    "points": ["d"],
 scores:[4]
 
}]'

Comment: I found the answer to my second question in the comments. The answer can be found here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426022/mongodb-show-children-items-in-one-to-many-relationship)